# push app from root adb terminal

Tags: root-access, lg

So i have a rooted ms690, but su keeps crashing, the recovery is just a hard reset, I have no sd card, and metroweb is gone. The problem I want to solve is metroweb. I have the apk, and the only way I can get to root anything is this:

```
adb shell
$ su
#
```

What do i do from here?

Answer (score 2):

And what to do before that, also important. OK, short guide – assuming your `.apk` has the name `metro.apk`, and you're in the very same directory on your computer where that file resides:

```
PC> adb push metro.apk /data/local/metro.apk
PC> adb shell
$ su
# pm install /data/local/metro.apk
```

What I'm just wondering: What makes you think you need to be root for that? Taking the shorter road:

```
PC> adb install metro.apk
```

Saves a few steps :)

OTOH, if you're talking about a system app, things might look different:

```
PC> adb push metro.apk /data/local/metro.apk
PC> adb shell
$ su
# mount -ro remount,rw /system
# cp /data/local/metro.apk /system/app
# exit
PC> adb reboot
```

Comment: I don't have an sd card, so /data/ is empty when I try this

Comment: Nevermind, it's there. I can't remount system as rw.

Comment: I used '# mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system' to remount system, but cp gives me 'cp: not found' so I used mv and I got 'failed on 'Browser.apk' - Cross-device link'

Comment: Ok, used dd to get browser apk where i wanted it, but it's not showing up in my apps.

Comment: Used es file esplorer to set permissions and now it shows p, but crashes on launch'

Comment: `/data` is the *internal storage*, and `/data/local` is a kind of "temp directory" especially for things like this; I specifically chose a place available on all devices. No idea why `cp` failed. As for the crashes, it might help to investigate the logs (e.g. via `adb logcat`). I suspect dependencies (it might need another app/service to work).